# How can I implement groupby in one column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem about implementing groupby in one column.

After I wrote a code shown below, I created a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby(['year','Name']).size()}).reset_index()
```

Here is my dataframe

```
    year    Name    count
0   1950    a         3
1   1950    b         3
2   1951    c         2
3   1951    d         1
4   1951    e         3
```

What I want to do is to revise a dataframe shown below.

```
    year    Name    count
0   1950    a         3
            b         3
1   1951    e         3
            c         2
            d         1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use df.groupby([”year”, ”Name”])[”count”].cumcount().reset_index()  Sorry I am on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `set_index`

```
df = df.sort_values(['year','count'], ascending=[True,False]).set_index(['year','Name'])
           count
year Name       
1950 a         3
     b         3
1951 e         3
     c         2
     d         1
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce. How can I sort them by "count" column to  fix year column and order name and count column?

Comment: I already tried to put it at the end of code but I didn't work. I updated the dataframe in the post

Comment: @TonyBrand check again ~